# File Unlinking not Working when PHP Delete Link is Pressed

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, unlink

I am trying to make this link work:

```
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?del=true&product_code=".($row['product_code'])."' style='color:black;' onclick='return show_confirm();'>Delete</a>
```

It Delete's the specified row from the MSSQL table using the while function. Currently, the bottom code works fine in the sense that it deletes the specific row from the MSSQL table, but I would like it to also unlink a file from the `img` folder and another file from the `specsheets` folder.

The file that gets unlinked from `img` has it's filename stored in the `product_img_name` column for that table row and the other file has its filename stored in the `specsheet` column. Each table row has these two columns that contains unique file names from the files that are located in the `img`, and `specsheets` folder.

So far when I hit delete I am getting these **errors**:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'G1013' to data type int. (severity 16) in D:\Hosting\dl\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1175

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hosting\dtscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1175

Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\Hostingdtml\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1175

Warning: unlink(img/) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in D:\Hostingdml\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1177

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'G1013' to data type int. (severity 16) in D:\Hostingdml\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1179

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hostindhtml\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1179

Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\Hosting\dhtml\partscatalogue\partscataloguemanagement.php on line 1179
```

My problem in simple terms is when a table row gets deleted, the file for that row in my website's `img` folder and the file for that row in my website's `specsheets` folder remain and do not get deleted with the row.

Here is the code for when the delete link is hit for that specific row:

```
// delete from table
if ($_GET['del'] == 'true') {
   // cast id as int for security
   $product_code = $_GET['product_code'];
   $fileas = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select product_img_name from products where product_code = $product_code"));
     if (file_exists("img/$fileas")) {
   unlink("img/$fileas");   
     }
   $file38 = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select specsheet from products where product_code = $product_code"));
     if (file_exists("spechsheets/$file38")) {
   unlink("specsheets/$file38"); 
     }
   // delete row from table
   $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_code = '$product_code'";
   $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die();
   } // end if del
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (file_exists($fileas)) {unlink("img/$fileas"); }` -- you're checking a path, then unlinking a totally different path.. `$fileas` !== `img/$fileas`

Comment: Also look at some of the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#101637) on php.net about the function `unlink`. The unlink function may not be doing what you think it is. Further the `unlink` function returns True on success and False on failure; you could check to see if unlink works as a check before deleting the entry in MySQL

Comment: I have updated my question and updated the code you were stating above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your directory structure is here but for instance you are checking if $fileas exists but then trying to unlink img/$fileas, which is not the same place.  If img/$fileas is the correct path, that is also what you need to place in the file_exists() to get the correct check.  So it would be file_exists(img/$fileas), etc.

Comment: I corrected the file path and I am still getting errors. I have updated the code/errors in my question.

Comment: I've never used Mssql so I am assuming it works similar to MySql here.  I assume product_img_name is the actual file name you are trying to get?  At the moment $fileas is an array of the first row (in this case only row, if your database is set up with product_code as a unique field) returned from the database, to access the data for product_img_name you would need to use $fileas['product_img_name'].  You could do an echo on $fileas['product_img_name'] to make sure it is getting what you want.  File_exists and unlink will both need the file extension too, I believe.